# What's the meaning of this

Tags: c#, constructor

What is the meaning of this following section on [constructor initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645603%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

> An instance constructor initializer cannot access the instance being created. Therefore it is a compile-time error to reference `this` in an argument expression of the constructor initializer, as is it a compile-time error for an argument expression to reference any instance member through a simple-name.

Comment: +1 cause the author cannot be blamed for Microsofts documentation and I think it is kind of stuff which is not known by many people.

Comment: @alina what is wrong with the documentation and why is it subject to blame?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, except that people vote down the question without leaving any comment.

Answer (score 8):

This means the instance is still in the process of being created when the constructor initializer runs. Therefore, that initializer cannot access instance members, either through `this` or directly:

```
class Foo
{
    private int _bar;

    public Foo(int bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    public Foo() : this(_bar)       // Illegal.
    {
    }

    public Foo() : this(this._bar)  // Also illegal.
    {
    }
}
```

This reasoning applies to both constructor initializers (`this()` and `base()`).